# mapping dictionary and lists python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

What the easiest way if you have three lists

```
list [1,2,3] [a,b,c] [5,6,7]
```

to map it with a dictionary

```
{1:{'a':5}, 2:{'b':6}, 3:{'c':7}}
```

Got a feeling you have to use zip ..

How would this be done in python where dictionary comprehension isn't possible

Comment: dictionary is not ordered. why can't the result be `{1:{'b':6}, 2:{'a':5}, 3:{'c':7}}`?

Comment: dictionaries don't have order.  How should you know that `1` goes with `{a:5}`?

Comment: feels nice to beet @mgilson even once, even it's only 2 sec!

Comment: yep will rephrase the question

Comment: Dictionary comprehensions _are_ possible in 2.7.

Answer (score 6):

The 3-list case in your update is an easy one with `zip`:

```
d = {k:{k1:v1} for k,k1,v1 in zip(list1,list2,list3)}
```

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries don't have an order, so I am assuming you want to map them based on the order of the sorted keys.  You can do that with the following:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> dct = {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}
>>> {i: {k: dct[k]} for i, k in zip(lst, sorted(dct))}
{1: {'a': 5}, 2: {'b': 6}, 3: {'c': 7}}
```

If you decide to use something like list of tuples instead of a dictionary to maintain the order, you could do the following:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> tups = [('a', 5), ('b', 6), ('c', 7)]
>>> {i: {k: v} for i, (k, v) in zip(lst, tups)}
{1: {'a': 5}, 2: {'b': 6}, 3: {'c': 7}}
```

Comment: I believe the input is three lists and the desired output is a dict mapping them as shown in question.

Comment: I answered before the OP edited the question, original version had a dict in place of the second two lists.

Answer (score 0):

Are the values in first & second list can be duplicated, for example:

```
a, b, c = [3,1,2,3,1], ['a','a','b','c','d'], [1,5,6,7,8]
```

If you need the order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict()
for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c):
    if x not in od:
        od[x] = OrderedDict()
    od[x][y] = z
print od
```

output:

```
OrderedDict([(3, OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('c', 7)])), (1, OrderedDict([('a', 5), ('d', 8)])), (2, OrderedDict([('b', 6)]))])
```

if you don't need order:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(dict)
for x, y, z in zip(a,b,c):
    dd[x][y] = z
print dd
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {1: {'a': 5, 'd': 8}, 2: {'b': 6}, 3: {'a': 1, 'c': 7}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **izip** which is better in terms of efficiency

```
from itertools import izip

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = [5, 6, 7]

print {a: {b: c} for a, b, c in izip(a, b, c)}
```

**Output:**

```
{1: {'a': 5}, 2: {'b': 6}, 3: {'c': 7}}
```